# (Unity3D) Paint with soft brush (logic)

Tags: unity-game-engine, paint, brush

During the last few days i was coding a painting behavior for a game am working on, and am currently in a very advanced phase, i can say that i have 90% of the work done and working perfectly, now what i need to do is being able to draw with a "soft brush" cause for now it's like am painting with "pixel style" and that was totally expected cause that's what i wrote, 
my current goal consist of using this solution :

1. import a brush texture, [this image](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/21317-brush_test.png)
2. create an array that contain all The alpha values of that texture
3. When drawing use the array elements in order to define the new pixels alpha

And this is my code to do that (it's not very long, there is too much comments)

```
//The main painting method
        //theObject     = the object to be painted
        //tmpTexture    = the object current texture
        //targetTexture = the new texture 
        void paint (GameObject theObject, Texture2D tmpTexture, Texture2D targetTexture)
        {
                //x and y are 2 floats from another class
                //they store the coordinates of the pixel 
                //that get hit by the RayCast
                int x = (int)(coordinates.pixelPos.x);
                int y = (int)(coordinates.pixelPos.y);

                //iterate through a block of pixels that goes fro
                //Y and X and go #brushHeight Pixels up
                // and #brushWeight Pixels right
                for (int tmpY = y; tmpY<y+brushHeight; tmpY++) {
                        for (int tmpX = x; tmpX<x+brushWidth; tmpX++) {
                                //check if the current pixel is different from the target pixel
                                if (tmpTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY) != targetTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY)) {
                                        //create a temporary color from the target pixel at the given coordinates
                                        Color tmpCol = targetTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY);
                                        //change the alpha of that pixel based on the brush alpha
                                        //myBrushAlpha is a 2 Dimensional array that contain
                                        //the different Alpha values of the brush
                                        //the substractions are to keep the index in range
                                        if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > 0) {
                                            tmpCol.a = myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
                                        }
                                        //set the new pixel to the current texture
                                        tmpTexture.SetPixel (tmpX, tmpY, tmpCol);
                                } 
                        }
                }
                //Apply 
                tmpTexture.Apply ();
                //change the object main texture 
                theObject.renderer.material.mainTexture = tmpTexture;
        }
```

Now the fun (and bad) part is the code did exactly what i asked for, but there is something that i didn't think of and i couldn't solve after spend the whole night trying, 
the thing is that by asking to draw anytime with the brush alpha i found myself create a very weird effect which is decreasing the alpha value of an "old" pixel, so i tried to fix that by adding an if statement that check if the current alpha of the pixel is less than the equivalent brush alpha pixel, if it is, then augment the alpha to be equal to the brush, and if the pixel alpha is bigger, then keep adding the brush alpha value to it in order to have that "soft brushing" effect, and in code it become this  :

```
                                                if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > tmpCol.a) {
                                                        tmpCol.a = myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
                                                } else {
                                                        tmpCol.a += myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
                                                }
```

But after i've done that, i got the "pixelized brush" effect back, am not sure but i think maybe it's because am making these conditions inside a for loop so everything is executed before the end of the current frame so i don't see the effect, could it be that ?
Am really lost here and hope that you can put me in the right direction,

Thank you very much and have a great day

Comment: I also tried to break the conditions but still didn't get the willing effect

Comment: Tags don't belong in the subject line. Don't post the same thing in two places without crosslinks.